# How to tell if the t-SNE algorithm produces the same result?

Tags: data-science

I am studying the t-SNE algorithm and came across a question and found no answer about it. If I have the same dataset and run the t-SNE algorithm multiple times with the same number of iterations and the same number of perplexity, will I get the same views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but the condition for this is the same number of perplexity.